# Are these the correct 2nd partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

This is a problem I have attempted. I am given the first partial derivatives, and asked to find the second partial derivatives. Have I done it correclty?

[image]

Comment: The last one should be $\sum 2 x_i$.

Comment: Which one? The one which is 4x^2 right now?

Comment: Yes I think so @shrindle.